# Informatica how to POST JSON data with Bearer Token in Header

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, bearer-token

Having issue with http transformation simple post with bearer token.
So, we have a mapping that uses http transformation to SIMPLE POST JSON data into an api. The api uses bearer token authorization. So you send a user/pass and get a token back and then POST your json data with the token in the header.
But when we are trying to POST along with token, we are facing issues. Basically i am not sure how to post json data with token in the header info.
Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: It took me lot of time and research to find answer of this question. i posted answer only to help someone who faces this issue. pls consider the effort i put into this before downvoting it. sorry that you feel like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearer token is another token-based authorization technique where if you pass user/pass to the token-generating API, it returns a token. You attach that token to API tool (postman, insomnia, or informatica) and POST your data to another API which will process the data.
Now, issue is, token can expire fast or slow. Fast expiring token need to be managed so that API call finishes before expiry. For us luckily its 24hrs.
First, get the token using HTTP trx by passing userid/pass.
Then, I pass the token as part of header column in HTTP transformation.
Methods I used - SIMPLE POST for both trx.
[image]

EDIT : Per request from an user, i am  adding this edit.
The user and pass in the `EXP` transformation is hardcode values. And they were added to a json format that auth api can recognize.
The output of http_auth transformation is a token. If hardcode is a problem, you can read user and pass from a file from a secured location.

This token is used in the next json.  This next json is created using the token as well as input data to the actual api. The api catches them, validates them against token and then write the data into api DB.

Comment: Thank you Koushik for the post. What is the input to i_json_txt1? Also o_json_txt is carried forward as in_Data. What is the expression of o_json_txt?

Comment: i_json_txt is your actual data. o_json_txt is the data along with json strings  `{`, '}` or whatever your api accepts - basically formatting raw data into json format that api can accept. example `'{'|| in_json_txt||'}'. in my string i used '[]'.

Comment: Ok thank you. I am getting 403 Forbidden Error. Do you know any permissions or authentication or configuration that needs to be done in sharepoint for basic authentication through Informatica?

Comment: Yes, its authorization problem. Api is receiving input but nit authorized to answer. Check first using swagger if api is working for the input you r passing in  informatica. If yes, then check if informatica server is whitelisted in api. If yes, check if informatica has certificates added.

Comment: Tried with Swagger as well, i am not able to import the URL, its giving the same 403 forbidden error. Could you provide some insight on what certificate i need to add in Informatica and how that is done?

Comment: is postman/swagger call working?

Comment: here is the link for you. but pls be sure that swagger is working. https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/22877?language=en_US

Comment: No. Postman and swagger call not working. Thanks for the certificate link. Let me try that and update

Comment: Sharepoint admins say connection is possible only through client id, tenant id, secret key. Where do we put these in Informatica? It seems Microsoft dont allow user id, pwd login to sharepoint site.

Comment: i think you can first focus on swagger or postman. If they works, infa should work too. You can pass all of them thru https transformation using correct json string.

Comment: Do you have a sample json input format for getting the token? Also in the REST/HTTP connection in Session what should be the connection details? Because in my case there is no userid and password and no client certificate involved.

Comment: Its really depend on your api input requirements. Sample can be `{ "id": "xx","pass": "yy"}`. Try this json from swagger first, if it works, then use same json format.

Comment: Rest conn would be api url. Test it using swagger

Answer (score 1):

It worked with below approach for Barer token.

Flow:
SQ->exp->HTTP->exp->HTTP->TGT

HTTP connection:
Base URL : Provide the login URL for the API
Authentication : Basic

First HTTP transformation:
Give the login URL in Base URl. Pass a single row as an input for trigger of URL. This should give the generated token as an output (JSON/XML).
Pass the output to expression transf. Add a new output port and extract the token value only.
output port value : 'Bearer '||substr(ouput,2,30)
Methods - POST

Second HTTP transformation:
Add new input port and connect the above expression output as input.
Add new Header port as "Authorization".
Provide the API URL in the base url.
Methods - POST
Connect the output port to Flat file to check the received response.
Note: Do not give/select any connection details to this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Try postman.. It will give you the code as well. It supports quite a few commonly used development languages

Comment: thank you . I am using swagger. i can use postman/insomnia but the way postman sends POST data and the way informatica sends can be/is different. I am looking for a solution/idea using informatica. I can see how insomnia sends data and not sure how infa can send it like that.