# Informatica how to use REST API to GET data , WEB servis uses authorization.bearer token

Tags: http, transformation, informatica

I need to use  http transformation  to get the data using REST API but the api uses bearer token authorization. Can sobody can help me how create the mapping to retrive the data from the web ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below answer on how to use Informatica to request bearer token and then use it in subsequent process. This is answered assuming API output is JSON, but you can use it for any other output type like csv/xml.
Basically this is a 2 step process.

1. Request bearer token using user/pass through HTTP transformation. You may need a  non-expiary service user.
2. The bearer token you got form step 1 use it in next HTTP transformation which calls actual API.

[Informatica how to POST JSON data with Bearer Token in Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295470/informatica-how-to-post-json-data-with-bearer-token-in-header)