# How to authorize and connect to Rest webservice from informatica and post the data?

Tags: java, api, rest, etl, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping where I need to hit the Rest web service through informatica http transformation. I have two fields to pass as below format which I am converting in expression transformation and sending it as string to http transformation.

```
[
 {
   "id":"xxxx"
   "email":"yyyyy"
  }
]
```

I have not configured anything in the header. The rest service developer said they will send a consumer key which we need to pass to connect to rest service. Is there anything I need to configure in the header in the http transformation. Do I need to use any other http transformation in the mapping level. Attached screenshot of the mapping.[Mapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQT6M.jpg)

Comment: Please refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295470/informatica-how-to-post-json-data-with-bearer-token-in-header/63352194#63352194

Comment: okay thanks but how you're passing username and password like in json format in expression transformation

Comment: its in the answer. hardcoded value in json format exactly like API expects - `{
   "id":"xxxx"
   "pass":"yyyyy"
  }`. Now, if your API expects email, you can pass email. The return values are also imp

Comment: in expression - create a new column like this `out_api_string ='{    "id":"'||inp_id||  '"    "pass":"' || inp_pass|| '"   }'`. Then use this as input to your http transformation. Pls note in above exp, i assumed inp_id, inp_pass coming from a file and you can pass hardcoded value as well.

Comment: salesforce create connected app where pass consumer key()client-id) and consumer secret along with 
grant-type:password 
client_id:
client_secret: 
username: 
password 
response: 
"access token": 
"instance url": 
"id" :hhtps:test.salesforce.com/xxxxx/yyyyy
"token type" "bearer"

Comment: in the next request we send data along with token . 1>for json data type we have to convert in expression transformtn or the http transformation by default converts it?
 2> is the token we use in the header or body. seems similar scenario of urs. 
3>is there any configtn needs to be made in deafult tab and http name in http transmtn

Comment: 1- you have to create a valid json in exp. 2 - body 3 - probably not but make sure you can reach the api from informatica. You may need some certificate to be added if there is some certificate issues.