# How to call APIs in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: http, get, informatica-powercenter

My inquiry is there's a possible way to call APIs in Informatica Powercenter?
I tried to use two transformations like HTTP, Web Service Consumer (WSC) Transformations.
It's really complex and not clear for me to understand.
For example, when I use the WSC transformation I gave it the API URL but it Gives me an error:

> Failed to download the url.

When I use HTTP Transformation it requires things to enter like:

> Default Value
> HTTP Name

but I don't understand what are those used for; I only have the API URL to enter in the `Base URL` field.

Comment: can you pls refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295470/informatica-how-to-post-json-data-with-bearer-token-in-header