Informatica 10.4 on-prem export-import objects via rest api
Does informatica 10.4 on-prem server supports export-import via rest Api ? need an example.
looked all over and tried al AI's - still unsure that it is supported. most documents are for the cloud base version. This is what i got from some AI
curl -X GET 
'https://<infa_domain>:/rs/v1/repos/{repositoryName}/export-import/folders/{folderPath}/mapping/{mappingName}?format=xml' 
-H 'X-Credential-User: ' 
-H 'X-Credential-Password: ' 
-H 'Accept: application/xml' 
--output {mappingName}.xml

you can use http transformations to call API. But you need to use it properly. You have to pass correct parameters in proper json format and format the output properly.

do you have any Informatica reference doc?

I've never seen APIs that would allow this. The PowerCenter 10.4 documentation doesn't mention it.
In PowerCenter this is done by using pmrep command utility (docs), so for any automations you should run scripts on the backend where the pmrep is accessible.

i had a question and answer earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295470/informatica-how-to-post-json-data-with-bearer-token-in-header
